# Run an SSH command on two hosts whose name comes from another command

Tags: shell, ssh

So what I'm trying to do should be fairly simple but I can't seem to figure it out. I need to kill a certain process on different boxes, they all have a defined IP range although they will eventually change.

Let's say for example,

```
arp |sort |awk '{print $1}'|grep 10.20.30.18 # IP's range from 180 to 189 so this does the trick
```

output is

```
xxx.xxx.xxx.180
xxx.xxx.xxx.181
```

So I want to SSH into both and do

```
ps -ef | grep X11 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

How would I go on about this without having to SSH into each one and then killing the process?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `for` loop:

```
HOSTS='server1.example.com server2.example.com server3.example.com'

for server in $HOSTS
do
   ssh $server "ps -ef | grep X11 | grep -v grep | awk '{print \$2}' | xargs kill"
done
```

Or you could use one of the many apps already made for this. Like `clusterssh` and the like.

Comment: Or with help of some parallel ssh, like `pssh` or `shmux`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that all the hosts you want to kill the process on are in your arp cache?

Assuming the IPs are contiguous you might be better off simply iterating through the ips:

```
for i in {180..189}
do
 ssh -l username 10.20.30.$[i} "ps -ef | grep X11 | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill"
done
```